# What operating system is used according to enclosed picture?

Tags: linux, bsd, operating-system

Sorry for the beginner question but can one guess what OS this is from the named folder in the structure?

I was not allowed to post the picture but perhaps the link works. (have no text-based img).

[image: Super-mysterious Operating System...]

Comment: This being a relevant question because?

Comment: So a question about this as to what "operatingsystem" the folders in the structure hints at is not a question to ask at this forum? Being visited by both BSD and LINUX people it should be a simple question needing a quick response? Do you not know the OS? I think it is as the person wrote being "FreeBSD" but this is to settle a discussion and we needed some external input.

Comment: This isn't a forum.  Also, boot the system and run uname -r.

Comment: Yes, that folder structure do look FreeBSD:ish to me too. Still don't see why we would like to play that guessing-game.

Comment: I do not have access to the system (and the picture is obviously from a windows machine) we have a .tar.gz from a system and we want to know is it linux or bsd? From the folder structure depicted in the image above. If it is a question for this or any other "forum" I think is up to the moderators and not a discussion for the comment section don't you agree?

Comment: Definitely some unix variant. Most of the directories you'd expect to find on a Linux system, but not all of them. Filenames in `boot` as well as the presence of any `etc/*-release` files could provide additional hints.

Comment: Is this a homework problem of some type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird question.

It's probably FreeBSD, based on the `/etc/devd` and `/etc/boot/zfs` presence.

Comment: Thanks! I was almost certain since the init.d was not around in the /etc catalog. Most appreciated.